# Where is MutableStateFlow class?

Tags: kotlin

perhaps this question will be 'stupid' for some people, but where could I find the implementation to use to access at MutableStateFlow class?

I know, I know : RTFM! But I already read the f... manual and on the official site, we can't find the solution. So perhaps somebody has found, LUCKILY, the solution of my problem?

I add that my Android Studio is updated, I have the last SDK, the last Kotlin plugin, the last all...

Thanks by advance.
Andev

Comment: I found this in the package kotlinx.coroutines.flow

Comment: My question is "where could I found the information?" not "what is the solution?". However if you use import kotlinx.coroutines.flow.*, you'll see your MutableStateFlow will be not recognize. :(

Answer (score 0):

I guess you have to add below dependency for `StateFlow` which has `MutableStateFlow`

```
dependencies{
  implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core-jvm:1.3.9"
}
```

Comment: Found a solution here : https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines. It seems to be more recent : "implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:1.4.2'".